# How to create a custom package for PhoneGap Application?

Tags: android, cordova

If i create a phonegap application from command line i can create a phonegap android project
with proper name By

> phonegap create testapp --"com.test.app" -- name "TestApp"

But package is :

> com.phonegap.helloworld

Why Phonegap creates this random package although I provide com.test.app?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   phonegap create testapp com.test.app TestApp
```